# Continuity of a probability integral with supremum

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $m: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow [0,1] $ be a probability measure *without point masses* and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be *continuous*. Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Define the mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow [0,1]$ as
$$ \varphi(x) \ := \ m\left( \left\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n \left| \  \sup_{y \in \{x\} + \epsilon \mathbb{B} } f(v,y)>0\right.  \right\} \right). $$

Question: is $\varphi$ continuous?

Comment: How do you define the supremum of sets over all $y$ in the neighborhood?

Comment: You are right, thanks. I adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean $f(v,y)$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $n = m = 1$. Let $f(a,b) = b$.

If $x \leq -\epsilon$, $\sup_{y \in \{x\} + \epsilon B} f(\nu,y) \leq 0$ for any $\nu$, hence $\varphi(x) = m(\emptyset) = 0$.

For $x > -\epsilon$, $\sup_{\cdots} f(\nu,y) = b+ \epsilon + x > 0$ for any $\nu$ and hence $\varphi(x) = m(\mathbb{R}) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So under what conditions on $f$, may the claim be true?

Comment: The function $f$ that I gave (which also works in arbitrary dimensions), is about as good as a function can be! The problem is that $$\varphi(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} H(\sup_{y\in \{x\}+ \epsilon B} f(\nu,y)) \mathrm{d}m(\nu) $$ The integral operation would be "continuous" if the integrand is a bounded function continuous in $x$; so is the evaluation of the supremum. The only part that is discontinuous is the introduction of the Heaviside function. No matter what you do to $f$ you cannot change the fact that the Heaviside function is discontinuous!

Comment: The only hope I guess is to try to exploit the fact that $m$ has no atoms. One class of functions you can use is the class of functions for which $A_y = \{\nu | f(\nu,y) = 0\}$ has measure zero for every $y$ (or something like that), so the discontinuity in $H$ only occurs on a measure zero set.

Comment: In fact, "_without point masses_" I actually meant "_atomless_". So, do you think that a reasonable setting is the following? $g$ such that for all $y$, $m( v \mid f(v,y) = 0 ) = 0$, $m$ atomless, and $f$ jointly continuous?

Comment: What you want is certainly true for such class; whether such a class is reasonable... well, it depends on context.

Comment: Can you please formally explain/show that the above claim is true for such a class? Thanks a lot again.