# Continuity of a level-sets mapping

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a *continuous* function.

Define the set-valued mapping $S: \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^m$ as $$S(x) := \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^m \left| \ f(x,y)>0 \right. \right\}.$$

Question 1. is $S$ continuous?

Question 2. Let $f$ be continuous only on the first argument. Is $S$ continuous?

Comment: What is $\delta \mathbb B$? The frontier of the unit ball?

Comment: $\delta$ is a positive real number. $\mathbb{B}$ is the unitary closed ball. But I made the question easier for ease of understanding.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity for set-valued mappings?

Comment: The usual one: Section 5.B in http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is allowed to cheat with the question, the mapping $S$ can be discontinuous even if $f$ is continuous in the two arguments.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=\vert xy\vert$. Then $S(x)=\mathbb R\setminus\{ 0\}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $S(0)=\emptyset$, so $S$ is certainly not continuous at $0$.

This is cheating because it doesn't answer the question for a function $f$ such that $S(x)$ is always $\neq\emptyset$. $A\;better\;example\;is\;given\;in\;the\; comments\;below$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess this is exploiting the fact that $S$ is open-valued. What happens if we have $S(x) := \{ y \mid f(x,y) \geq 0 \}$?

Comment: Even in this case $S$ may be discontinuous. Take $f(x,y)=xy$. Then $S(x)= [0,\infty)$ if $x> 0$, $S(0)=\mathbb R$ and $S(x)=(-\infty,0]$ if $x>0$. So again $S$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You may be interested also in [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411949/continuity-of-a-probability-integral-with-supremum].